# Swift method to return a tuple in objective c class

Tags: swift

I would like to return two objects from a method using swift.

How can this method be added to an existing objective c class to access the tuple from where ever the method is called, in non swift files?

Does the tuple need to be created in a swift class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tuple is not compatible in `objective c`.You can use `Dictionary` instead of `tuple` .From swift [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).

> You’ll have access to anything within a class or protocol that’s
>   marked with the @objc attribute as long as it’s compatible with
>   Objective-C. This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed
>   here:
>
> ```
> Generics
> Tuple     //Tuple cannot be acesses from objective c
> Enumerations defined in Swift
> Structures defined in Swift
> Top-level functions defined in Swift
> Global variables defined in Swift
> Typealiases defined in Swift
> Swift-style variadics
> Nested types
> Curried functions
> ```
>
> For example, a method that takes a generic type as an argument or
>   returns a tuple will not be usable from Objective-C.

You cannot use these types in `objective c` in which `tuple` is included and cannot be accessed and it is not bind with any type in `objective c` and not compatible with `objective c`.

However you can do each and every thing with `Swift Dictionaries` that you can do with tuple.**Use `Dictionary` instead of tuple.**

Comment: Dictionaries require that you share knowledge somehow about what keys exist and what types are stored for those keys. Structs allow the IDE and the compiler to tell you exactly what is within the returned structure.

Comment: @drewag in this way `tuples` also require to have that knowledge what type stored in them.

Comment: no, the compiler and therefore the IDE know exactly what is in a tuple and exactly what type it is. When a dictionary transfers over to Objective-c everything will have type 'id' and the keys will not be known. With a tuple, even in objective-c the available values and their types will still be known.

Comment: Actually `tuple` cannot be bridged to `objective c` and if it is it may have id type because dictionaries are also `typed` in swift but in objective c they have the elements of id.

Comment: I am not suggesting the tuples should be used, I am suggesting that a struct should be used

Comment: From docs:"You cannot use object pointers in C structures.Rather than using a struct, you can create an Objective-C class to manage the data instead."So structures may not be as good for purpose.Whats your thought?

Comment: those objects need to make _unsafe_unretained as @Helium suggest so its little bit messy to use struct.

Comment: Ok ya, thanks for clarifying. I didn't realize that structs didn't interoperate better with Objective-C. I forgot that structs in Objective-C are just C structs.

Comment: Things got better in Swift 2.x, tuple components can be named e.g. in the return statement, and then you can use those names when accessing the values.  That doesn't help with ObjC of course, so I add helper method that sticks the values in a dict for Obj/C, but keep the tuple goodness for Swift.

Comment: Keys of dictionaries can be fetched with `.allKeys`. These days NSDictionary can be typed like `NSDictionary<NSString*, NSNumber*>* mydic = ...`.